Listar datos de una tabla bajo una condicional de otra tabla
Actualmente poseo un proyecto en laravel pero mi compañero programador ha desaparecido y es quien se encarga del trabajo pesado, pues soy menos experimentado.
Tengo un problema con una vista, poseo diversas tablas:
1-Cuentas
2-Usuarios
3-Servicios
4-Suscripciones
5-Perfiles
Tengo una vista que genera suscripciones, la cual me muestra a través de un select los servicios disponibles en el sistema, luego las cuentas asociadas al servicio y al User_id, luego puedo ver los perfiles que están asociados a las cuentas y que están disponibles (es decir que no han sido utilizados), para poder realizar entonces una suscripción de 1 Servicio en una cuenta X, y un perfil X de dicha cuenta.
La situación que presento es que necesito que así como me lista SOLO los perfiles que están vacíos; entonces que me liste solo las cuentas que poseen perfiles vacíos o disponibles. Pues cuando elijo una cuenta que no posee perfiles disponibles me toca seleccionar uno a uno los correos para ver cual posee perfiles disponibles.
Esta es la vista de una nueva suscripción

Se listan los servicios

Se muestran las cuentas que pertenecen a ese servicio

Los perfiles disponibles para la cuenta de ejemplo pedro@gmail.com

**Para el caso de la cuenta jua01@gmail.com (no posee perfiles a su nombre disponibles y por ende la lista de perfiles está vacía.)

Lo que necesito es evitarme la molestia de ir cuenta por cuenta viendo si tiene perfiles libres o no.
Dentro de mi SubscriptionController tengo estas funciones que van a este asunto en cuestion:
public function getAccounts($service_id){
    $data = [];
    $attr = [
        'table'=>'accounts',
        'columns'=>[
            'id',
            'email'
        ],
        'compare'=>'service_id',
        'compare_value'=>$service_id
    ];
    $response = Helper::getDataSelect($attr,auth()->user()->id);
    if($response){
        $data = $response;
    }

    return response()->json(['data'=>$data]);
}

public function getProfiles($account_id){
    $data = [];
    $attr = [
        'table'=>'profiles',
        'columns'=>[
            'id',
            'name',
            'pin'
        ],
        'compare'=>'account_id',
        'compare_value'=>$account_id
    ];
    $response = Helper::getDataSelect($attr);
    if($response){
        foreach($response as $res){
            $profile = Profile::find($res->id);
            if($profile->subscriptions->count() == 0){
                array_push($data, $res);
            }
        }
    }

    return response()->json(['data'=>$data]);
}

Dentro del Helper tengo esta funcion
public static function getDataSelect($attr,$user_id=null){
        if($attr){
            if($user_id){
                $data = DB::table($attr['table'])->select($attr['columns'])->where($attr['compare'],$attr['compare_value'])->where('user_id',$user_id)->get();
            }else{
                $data = DB::table($attr['table'])->select($attr['columns'])->where($attr['compare'],$attr['compare_value'])->get();
            }

            return $data;
        }else{
            return null;
        }

    }

Y por último en mi vista tengo un script que tiene que ver con los selects
    @extends('adminlte::page')

@section('title', $title)

@section('content')
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card card-success">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h2><i class="fas fa-star"></i> {{ $title }}</h2>
                </div>
                @include('admin.partials.form', ['element'=>'subscriptions', 'type'=>$type, 'id'=>@$data->id])
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Servicio:</label>
                            <select name="service_id" class="form-control form-control-sm @error('service_id') is-invalid @enderror">
                                <option value="-1">Seleccione</option>
                                @foreach($services as $service)
                                    <option value="{{$service->id}}">{{$service->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                            @error('service_id')
                               <span class="error invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Cuenta:</label>
                            <select name="account_id"  class="form-control form-control-sm @error('account_id') is-invalid @enderror">
                                <option value="-1" >Seleccione</option>
                            </select>
                            @error('account_id')
                               <span class="error invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Perfil:</label>
                            <select name="profile_id" class="form-control form-control-sm @error('profile_id') is-invalid @enderror">
                                <option value="-1">Seleccione</option>
                            </select>
                            @error('profile_id')
                               <span class="error invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Cliente:</label>
                            <select name="customer_id" class="form-control form-control-sm @error('customer_id') is-invalid @enderror">
                                <option>Seleccione</option>
                                @foreach($customers as $customer)
                                    <option value="{{$customer->id}}">{{$customer->name}} ({{$customer->phone}})</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                            @error('customer_id')
                               <span class="error invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Monto:</label>
                            <input type="number" step="0.01" name="amount" class="form-control @error('amount') is-invalid @enderror" />
                            @error('amount')
                               <span class="error invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Instrumento:</label>
                            <select name="paymeth_id" class="form-control form-control-sm @error('paymeth_id') is-invalid @enderror">
                                <option value="-1">Seleccione</option>
                                @foreach($paymeths as $paymeth)
                                    <option value="{{$paymeth->id}}">{{$paymeth->instrumento}} ({{$paymeth->moneySymbol}})</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                            @error('paymeth_id')
                               <span class="error invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Referencia:</label>
                            <input type="number" step="0.01" name="referencia" class="form-control @error('referencia') is-invalid @enderror" />
                            @error('referencia')
                               <span class="error invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Vencimiento:</label>
                            <input type="date" name="date_to" class="form-control @error('date_to') is-invalid @enderror" />
                            @error('date_to')
                               <span class="error invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        @include('admin.partials.buttons',['cancelRoute'=>'subscriptions.index'])
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@stop

@section('js')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select").select2();
            $("select[name='service_id']").change(function(){
                let id = $(this).val();
                if(id != '-1'){
                    $.get('/admin/get-accounts/'+id, function(response){
                        let data = response.data;
                        if(data.length > 0){
                            $("select[name='account_id']").html("<option value='-1'>Seleccione</option>");
                            $.each(data, function(v,e){
                                $("select[name='account_id']").append("<option value='"+e.id+"'>"+e.email+"</option>");
                            });
                        }
                    })
                }else{
                    $("select[name='account_id']").html("<option>Seleccione</option>");
                }
            });

            $("select[name='account_id']").change(function(){
                let id = $(this).val();
                if(id != '-1'){
                    $.get('/admin/get-profiles/'+id, function(response){
                        let data = response.data;
                        if(data.length > 0){
                            $("select[name='profile_id']").html("<option value='-1'>Seleccione</option>");
                            $.each(data, function(v,e){
                                $("select[name='profile_id']").append("<option value='"+e.id+"'>"+e.name+" ("+e.pin+")</option>");
                            });
                        }
                    })
                }else{
                    $("select[name='profile_id']").html("<option value='-1'>Seleccione</option>");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
@stop

Espero que puedan prestarme su apoyo con esto, pues he intentado darle la vuelta pero no lo logro.
